# Writing a file using a different account in Spring Integration

Tags: file-io, spring-integration

Using Spring Integration file:outbound-channel-adapter, is there a way to specify what user account to use when writing the file. We need to write files from one domain to another. We would like to be able to write them just using file shares, but to do this, we need to be able to log in to the remote box with an account in the remote domain.

We can get around this with FTP, but would like to use file writing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about windows domains/shares.

There are SMB adapters in the [Spring Integration Extensions](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-smb) repository.

It includes a [sample configuration file](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-extensions/blob/master/spring-integration-smb/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/smb/config/SmbOutboundChannelAdapterSample-context.xml).

You can build it from github or there's a snapshot in the spring snapshot repo.